# Numba AOT compile functions with functional arguments

Tags: python, numba, aot

I am trying to AOT compile in Numba a function which has a functional argument, but I cannot find a way to correctly specify its signature. Using a very basic example, with the standard numba `@njit` decorator, I would write:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(nb.f8(nb.f8, nb.f8))
def fcn_sum(a, b): 
    return a + b

@nb.njit(nb.f8(nb.typeof(fcn_sum), nb.f8, nb.f8))
def test(fun, a, b): 
    return fun(a, b)
```

where `nb.typeof(fcn_sum)` returns a dispatcher object that is valid only for the `fcn_sum` function. Unfortunately, the same strategy for AOT compilation generates a `NameError` error because both `nb` and `typeof` are not recognised:

```
@cc.export('test', 'f8(nb.typeof(fcn_sum), f8, f8)')
def test(fun, a, b):
    return fun(a, b)
```

How can I specify the signature of functional arguments to make this example work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error when you use the same signature as in the @njit case:

```
@cc.export('test', nb.f8(nb.typeof(fcn_sum), nb.f8, nb.f8))
def test(fun, a, b):
    return fun(a, b)
```

Comment: Thought the function signatures could only be passed as a string. That solved it, thank you!